# If $F$ is a finite group, then any finitely generated element of ${\rm Var}(F)$ is finite

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, finitely-generated

This is Robinson "A Course in the Theory of Groups" Ex. 2.3.10

Let $F$ be a finite group.

Notation: $(F)$ denotes the class of all groups either trivial or isomorphic to $F$.
${\rm Var}(F)$ is the intersection of all varieties containing $(F).$

Show, if $G$ is a finitely generated member of ${\rm Var}(F),$ then $G$ is itself finite.

---

I believe it's true that $G$ must be an image of a subgroup of a Cartesian product of $(F)$-groups.  So w.l.o.g., $G$ is an image of a subgroup of a Cartesian product of copies of $F$ itself.  Is this correct?

First, as a simpler case, suppose $G'$ is a f.g. cartesian product, ${\rm Cp}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}F_\lambda$ of copies of (finite) $F$.  Suppose $X = \{X_1...X_n\}$ is finite and $G' = \langle X\rangle$.  It's clear that if two components $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are such that $X_{i,\lambda} = X_{i,\mu}$ for all $i\in\{1..n\}$ then those components are essentially identical, and could be collapsed into one.  But $X$ and $F$ are finite, therefore only a finite number of components can be different, and can't be collapsed.  So w.l.o.g. we can assume $\Lambda$ is finite, and therefore $G'$ is finite.

However, I don't know how to extend this argument (if it can be extended) to subgroups, let alone images of subgroups.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: The exercise gives you a hint, which it might have been helpful to mention.

Comment: What do you mean "subsets"? An element in the variety is a quotient of a sub**group** of a cartesian power. And a finitely generated subgroup of $G/N$ is a quotient of a finitely generated subgroup of $G$: if $x_1N,\ldots,x_kN$ generate $H\leq G/N$, then let $K=\langle x_1,\ldots,x_k\rangle$ and look at $K/K\cap N$, which is isomorphic to $KN/N$, which is $\langle x_1N,\ldots,x_kN\rangle$. Since $K$ is finite, so is $K/N$.

Comment: Thanks David A. Craven for reminding me... I've had this in my head all week and didn't check the source again.

Comment: Thanks Arturo Magidin -- I've fixed the typo.  Thanks for the solution... I will ponder it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question: yes, for any class of groups $\mathcal{X}$, Birkhoff's HSP Theorem says that $\mathrm{Var}(\mathcal{X})=\mathbf{HSP}(\mathcal{X})$, that is, it consists of groups that are homomorphic images of subgroups of cartesian products of groups in $\mathcal{X}$. When $\mathcal{X}=\{F\}$ a single group, then you get homomorphic images of subgroups of cartesian powers of $F$.

You are essentially done. You've proven that a finitely generated subgroup of a direct (cartesian) power of $F$ is finite. All that remains is to show that a finitely generated subgroup of a quotient of such a subgroup is also finite.

Let $G\leq \mathop{\mathrm{Cp}}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}F$ be a subgroup of a cartesian power, let $N\triangleleft G$, and let $K=G/N$. Let $x_1N,\ldots,x_kN\in K$. We want to show that $A=\langle x_1N,\ldots,x_kN\rangle$ is finite.

Let $\mathfrak{K}=\langle x_1,\ldots,x_k\rangle$ for any particular choice of coset representatives of the generators of $K$. Note that $\mathfrak{K}N$ is the subgroup of $G$ corresponding to $A$, so that $A\cong \mathfrak{K}N/N$. By the Second Isomorphism Theorem (or Third, depending how you number them), $\mathfrak{K}N/N\cong \mathfrak{K}/\mathfrak{K}\cap N$. Because $\mathfrak{K}$ is a finitely generated subgroup of $G$, it is a finitely generated subgroup of the cartesian power of $F$, and hence is finite by what you've already proven. Hence, $\mathfrak{K}/\mathfrak{K}\cap N$ is a quotient of a finite group, hence is itself finite. Thus, $A$ is finite, which is what we wanted to prove. $\Box$

Comment: Thank you Arturo.  It always seems so simple when someone else does it.  My brain is too old!

Comment: I was thinking some more about your answer.  I think we only need the case where A is the whole of K (ie HSP, not SHSP)?  It's not wrong, but this would slightly simplify the proof.  I'm pleased to see a clear application of that 2nd Isomorphism Theorem, because, though I learned it almost 40 years ago (!) I hadn't until now seen the point of it.

Comment: @AndrewKay: I think you are confused. We are trying to prove that the *finitely generated* elements of the variety are finite, not that every element in the variety is finite (it isn't, unless your group is trivial). If you just take an arbtirary quotient of a subgroup of a product, that group need not be finitely generated, and hence need not be finite.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure.  First, since K is an image of a subgroup of the Cp (and therefore a general element of the variety) isn't it enough to show that K f.g. implies K finite?  Whereas above we show that any f.g. subgroup A of K is finite.  I'm not trying to be picky, just trying to understand.  Thank you again.

Comment: @AndrewKay: How do you know that a finitely generated subgroup of a homomorphic image of a subgroup of a cartesian product is equal to a homomorphic image of a finitely generated subgroup of a cartesian?  You need to prove that first to use your approach. And you can prove it... by doing exactly what I'm doing above.